# SQL Join on multiple columns of the same table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables for Administrative Divisions as below. I'm trying to get the Municipality Name for each Parish.

**municipalities**

```
id       | district_id | name     |
---------|-------------|----------|
01       | 01          | Abc      |
01       | 02          | Cba      |
01       | 03          | Random   |
...
```

**parishes**

```
id  | municipality_id | district_id | name |
----|-----------------|-------------|------|
03  | 01              | 01          | Abc  |
09  | 01              | 02          | Zxe  |
12  | 01              | 01          | Tfg  |
19  | 01              | 03          | Qwe  |
```

Query that I tried with no success:

```
SELECT municipalities.Name FROM municipalities
JOIN parishes AS P 
  ON municipalities.id = P.municipality_id
  AND municipalities.district_id = P.district_id;
```

The names don't match. How can I change the query to have a Municipality name for each Parish? Ideally the result would be something like this:

```
id | municipality_name | parish_name
03 | Abc               | Abc
09 | Cba               | Zxe
...
```

Note: The id column for municipalities doesn't have a Primary Key Constraint.

Comment: can u just add P.* to the select portion of the query...it looks valid to me...assuming the unique constraint on munis is id/district combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the other columns you want after `SELECT`, making a comma-separated list of which columns you want, in the order you want them to be returned:

```
SELECT P.id, municipalities.name, P.name
  FROM municipalities
  JOIN parishes as P
  ...
```

Comment: That's it. I was not selecting the columns from the join table. Thanks, accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT p.id, m.name AS municipality_name, p.name AS parish_name
FROM municipalities m 
  JOIN parishes p ON m.id = p.municipality_id AND m.district_id = p.district_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the data field from table `parishes`

```
SELECT p.id, municipalities.Name, p.name
FROM municipalities
JOIN parishes AS P 
  ON municipalities.id = P.municipality_id
  AND municipalities.district_id = P.district_id;
```